# Identify objects by its position open cv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm very new into Image Processing libraries. I been looking into OpenCV. But I  have a question. 
What sort of algorithms could I use if I want to identify few similar objects in a room. 
Lets say 3 similar tables. 
With a camera I sign an identity to each of those tables, after I move the camera 
to a positon where the objects are out of sight, when pointing the camera back 
to them, the system can properly identify those objects with the initial ID and trigger action based in each id.
I read about aruco makers, but i would like to try the idea without have to attach markers.

Comment: SLAM: simultaneous localization and mapping

Comment: Thank you @Micka. I will read about

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of methods to choose from. You could use image features, color matching, shape matching, pattern matching ... and so on. It really depends on the specific use case and the environment. In any case you need something unique to distinguish the tables from each other. Using markers would be one way to artificially create uniqueness.

Maybe you wanna start reading here to get a feeling how one method works:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html

Could you provide an example set of images of the scenario?

Comment: Hi @TeddybearCrisis, at this point of my search i do not have image set. Only imagine you have several similar objects in a room. You want to record a video, butr first you want to identify the objects and its position in the space. As you get back into them the image processing will identify them back. I will look into SLAM and see what it tells me. Aruco markers are a possible option for me as well! Thank you for your time

Comment: If their position in space matters SLAM is indeed the way to go. Search for "visual monocular slam" if you want to solve it with a single "standard" RGB/Grayscale-camera. Funfact: many SLAM algorithms use SIFT internally. That's one of the feature detection algorithms provided with the link  in my original reply.